# php preg_match_all pattern for parentheses

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

I am trying to get every instance of a value between two parentheses (). My Function is returning every character in an array instead of the two strings in which it should. I'm guessing there is something in the pattern? I have been going at this for a while trying different methods. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$formula = "if([Paid] === 1, 'Need To Pay', 'Paid Up')+if([Paid] === 1, 'Million', 'Good to Go')"
```

my class:

```
<?php

class Formula {

    public function explode_formula($formula){
        echo $this->get_string_between($formula, "(", ")");
    }

    public function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        preg_match_all("~((.+?))~", $string, $m);
        print_r($m[1]);
    }

}
```

Nees to Return:

```
[Paid] === 1, 'Need To Pay', 'Paid Up'
[Paid] === 1, 'Million', 'Good to Go'
```

Comment: You'll have to escape literal `\(` parens for the regex to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex line by escaping the outer parenthesis:

```
From: preg_match_all("~((.+?))~", $string, $m);
To:   preg_match_all("~\((.+?)\)~", $string, $m);
```

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php